# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException. WHERE clause

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get a MySQL syntax error when running the file Aspirantes.java in NetBeans:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'telefono1 = '01
>   800 021 1000',telefono2 = '01 800 433 2000',carrera = 'IT',promedio =
>   '100',WHERE ficha = 6' at line 1

I can't figure out what's wrong. The java code can be seen (and downloaded) at http://www.mediafire.com/view/?i37ccovyvcky8ai. The error seems to be in the lines from 584 to 596, in the MySQL UPDATE sentence.

The "datos" table looks like this: [image]

Any idea on how can I solve this? Thank you so much in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's your current code:

```
sSQL = "UPDATE datos " +
            "SET apellido1 = ?," +
            "apellido2 = ?," +
            "nombre = ?," +
            "genero = ?," +
            "telefono1 = ?," +
            "telefono2 = ?," +
            "carrera = ?," +
            "promedio = ?," +  // <<== remove this trailing comma
            "WHERE ficha = " +id_actualizar;
```

the problem is you have extra `comma` before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: +! - Nice eyes.  I'd also recommend using a PreparedStatement instead of string concatentation.

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen it's such a bad practice to use string concatenation. I'll take that into account!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like to do is put the comma at the beginning on every line after the first:

```
update x=y
,a=b
,c=d
```

It looks odd add first, but is more consistent than putting it after and running into the situation that you have :)